# "Original error: Neither ANDROID_HOME nor ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable was exported." Even when already set in ~/.zshrc

Tags: java, android, environment-variables, environment

I've recently swapped from a macbook air to a mac pro(m1 chip, Ventura 13.2.1) for work. I never had any issues on the previous macbook with the same setup. After swapping over and doing my environment setups I'm facing this issue:

Original error: Neither ANDROID_HOME nor ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable was exported.

I've set my ~/.zshrc up as

```
#JAVA_HOME
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_361.jdk/Contents/Home

#ANDROID_HOME
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/name/Library/Android/sdk
PATH="/Users/name/Library/Android/sdk/tools:${PATH}"
PATH="/Users/name/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:$PATH}"
PATH="/Users/name/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:${PATH}"
```

Both return:
[image: Java_HOME and ANROID_HOME return]

I also have them set the same way in appium GUI configs.

I have no issues executing the web project, only our mobile. If I set ANDROID_HOME=/Users/name/Library/Android/sdk in the IDE, it works without issue. Why would this work when set in IDE but not work when set in my ~/.zshrc? Is something failing to source? There is no difference in the values. Alongside the loads of suggestions I tried from other threads here with no luck, I also tried swapping from zsh to bash and had the same issue when setting up in .bash_profile. Any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Check this line carefully: `PATH="/Users/name/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:$PATH}"`

You are missing a left bracket, `"{"` after the dollar sign.

Comment: Ah thank you! I overlooked that, updated with the bracket. Sadly it didn't, however fix the issue!

Comment: Try adding the keyword "export" before your PATH

Comment: @ChrisMersi hi, any chance to make it work on windows? I set the system environement variable ANDROID_PATH as "C:\Users\<myname>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk" but still getting the same error